# Asp.net core Kestrel server and CLI

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a problem about kestrel server in asp.net core. Would you mind answering it??
When I run the application from CLI, Instead of seeing “dotnet” in my browser,I see my project’s name on my browser.
I want to know why??

Comment: Non-sense, Explain more and clearly?

Comment: Browser or TaskManager?

Comment: We need more information to suggest any answers. Where are you seeing the project name? Is it on a browser tab? What kind of application is this? Web projects generally come default with a debug configuration that will launch a browser window. Are there any actual issues with your project, or do you just not like seeing the name?

Comment: I am running the below code in CLI to know which hosting process I am using : system. Diagnostics.process.GetCurrentProcess().processName;    and instead of seeing "dotnet" in the browser, I am seeing my assembly name